# How to get decimal number without decimal separator using OleDbDataAdapter (Fixed Length Text File)?

Tags: c#, text-files, fixed-width, decimal-point, oledbdataadapter

Let's suppose I have a fixed length text file with 3 columns, two of them are double with 2 decimal places but they have no separator (like a dot or comma):

```
21318545
22422523
65498798
65465463
```

Using OleDbDataAdapter I have to create a schema.ini file, and I'm trying like this:

```
[numbers.txt]
ColNameHeader=False
Format=FixedLength
NumberDigits=2
DecimalSymbol=
Col1="A" Short Width 2
Col2="B" Double Width 3
Col3="C" Double Width 3
```

And then retrieve the datatable:

```
var dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT A, B, C FROM [numbers.txt]", "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=numbers.txt;Extended Properties="text;HDR=NO;");

var dataTable = new DataTable();
dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
```

I would like to get a DataTable with the following values:

```
A   B       C
21  3.18    5.45
22  4.22    5.23
65  4.98    7.98
65  4.65    4.63
```

But just assigning empty to the `DecimalSymbol=` in schema.ini doesn't work. I woudn't like to do any calculations to retrieve these fields or even iterate the file/datatable to add the decimal separator for each number, to divide by 100 or something like that, because numbers.txt actually has too many double columns to parse.

Any idea would be appreciated.